# How do I create a partially overlapping shape in Sketch?

Tags: shapes, overlapping, layered, sketchapp

[image]

This is the effect I'm after. The pink line would be the 'tail' of the shape overlapping the circle, and the grey part would be a dropshadow from the tail on the circle. How do I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: Sketch is not the right software for logo design. It is made for UI design..I suggest you to use Illustrator that have more powerful tools for vector graphics.

Answer (score 0):

With Sketchapp you can do this like :

1. Create the logo shape
2. Add a round shape and substract the two object
3. Create the path that will be the white border with the shadow
4. Substract this path (4) with the combined shape
5. Ctrl + C and Ctrl + v the path (3)
6. Create a mask from the combined path and mask the path cloned
7. Add the shadow on your cloned path
8. 

Here is a screen with every shape / group you need to do this.

[image: Logo made with Sketch app]